# How can I prove that a convex body $K$ is $\rho$-invariant if and only if its support function is constant on the orbits of $G$ on the unit sphere

Tags: representation-theory

Let $\rho \colon G \rightarrow \mathrm{GL}(V)$ be a continuous representation of a compact group $G$. Let $\mathbf{S}$ denote the unit sphere in $V$ with respect to a $\rho$-invariant scalar product.
The question is almost in the title:
how can I prove that a convex body $K$ is $\rho$-invariant if and only if its support function is constant on the orbits of $G$ on $\mathbf{S}$.

What’s more, I understand from the notes where I took this question that there should be an intuitive way of seeing this fact, but I can’t see it.

Comment: Can you confirm that $K$ is a subset of $V$ and that $\rho$ invariant means that $\rho(g)(K)=K$ for each $g\in G$?

Comment: 1) Yes, $K$ is a subset of $V$

Comment: 2) With $\rho$ invariant I meant that for each $v\in K$ also $\rho(g)(v)\in K$